# How many rows can a CSV file contain?

Tags: c#

What is the maximum number of rows a CSV file can contain?

I would like to know a specific number, as my requirement is to allow the maximum number of entries.
Is this number dependent on the operating system, or is the size fixed?

Answer (score 3):

CSV is a text format. There are no formal restrictions on the file size nor number of columns or rows. The most official specification is [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) if you want some "formal" statement.

File systems and programs that read the file can impose their own restrictions. I.e. a lot of quickly written tools would not handle files large than 2Gb correctly (integer size limit), a lot of tools that read content to the memory first will hit memory limits.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Alexei answer I would like to specify that you can use [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) to find total line count (for files greater than 2GB).

```
 BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
 char lastChar = reader.ReadChar();
 char newChar = new char();
 int lineCount = 0;
 do 
 {
    newChar = reader.ReadChar();
    if (lastChar == '\r' && newChar == '\n')
    {  
        lineCount++;
    }
    lastChar = newChar;
 }  while( reader.PeekChar() != -1);
```

Comment: this works well, unless there is no \r or \n at the end of the last line. I added a charCount variable which I incremented if the if clause is false. if there is a new line I reset this count to zero. then at the end after the Do, i check the value of charCount. If its greater than 0, another line without a \r at the end exists and I increment the linecount